# Add antiforgery token in handlebars template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, handlebars.js, antiforgerytoken

I have changed a razor view to a handlebars template.

In the razor view:

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("Start", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { formTypeId = @Model.TypeId, organizationId = @Model.OrganizationId }))
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <input type="hidden" name="formTypeId" value="@Model.TypeId" />
     <input type="hidden" name="organizationId" value="@Model.OrganizationId" />
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Start</button>
 }
```

In the handlebars template:

```
<form action="{{StartLink}}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formTypeId" value="{{TypeId}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="organizationId" value="{{OrganizationId}}" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="submit">Start</button>
</form>
```

I am unsure how to add the antiforgery token to the handlebars form.

Answer (score 0):

ok here is what I came up with.

in my index.cshtml I pass an antiforgery token to the js that creates the handlebars template.

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            window.formListBuilder = new app.components.FormListBuilder({
                container: '#forms-container',
                baseUrl: '@baseUrl.ToString()',
                antiForgeryToken: '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()',
                currentUser: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(currentUser))')
            })
        });

    </script>
}
```

then in the handlebars template I use the antiforgery token.

```
<form action="{{StartLink}}" method="post">
                    {{{antiForgeryToken}}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="formTypeId" value="{{TypeId}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="organizationId" value="{{OrganizationId}}" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="submit">Start</button>
                </form>
```

is that an acceptable solution or does that bypass security in some way?